Keyboard on mobile opens and closes instantly after entering text input field
Using opencart 2.3.0.2 on mobile device. My keyboard opens then immediately closes after entering my text input field. I successfully used the below code to move the add to cart button and options to above the description but now when I try to enter text into the text field options my keyboard pops open and closes a second later.
It's my understanding (which is limited) that the window resize event should prevent this behavior but it's still happening with one present in the code.
<script>
    $(function(){
        // We create a function
        function moveCart(){
            // If user screen is smaller than 768 pixel
            if($(window).width() < 768 ){
                /*
                    select cart area including cart button, options, product title and ...
                    if you want to only move cart button use '#product' instead of '#content > .row > .col-sm-4'
                */
                $('#content > .row > .col-sm-4').removeClass('col-sm-4').addClass('moved-div');
                // now move it
                $('.moved-div').insertAfter('.thumbnails');
            } else {
                /*
                    if user resized his/her screen width and now screen is wider than 767 pixel and we moved cart area before, move it to its original place.
                */
                if($('.moved-div').length){
                    $('.moved-div').insertAfter('#content > .row > .col-sm-8').addClass('col-sm-4').removeClass('moved-div');
                }
            }
        }

        // run function 
        moveCart();

        $(window).resize(function(){
            // run function again if user resized screen
            moveCart();
        })
    });
</script>

